# Rotating Box2D StaticBody

Tags: rotation, libgdx, box2d

I know, that there has been question on this topic, but I can't get my StaticBody to rotate. Here is the code, where I try to rotate it:

```
BodyDef bDef = new BodyDef();
Body body;

bDef.position.set(x, HEIGHT-y);
bDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
angle = 50;
body = world.createBody(bDef);
PolygonShape pShape = new PolygonShape();
pShape.setAsBox(width, height);
FixtureDef fDef = new FixtureDef();
fDef.shape = pShape;
body.createFixture(fDef);

body.setTransform(body.getPosition(), (float) (angle*Math.PI/180));
```

Printing the value out with this line:

```
System.out.println(body.getTransform().getRotation()/(Math.PI/180));
```

Returns: `50.0000002530119`, but the box doesn't rotate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you are supposed to use setTransform on static bodies.

Are you using setTransform directly after creating the body?
Then you could try to set the angle on the b2BodyDef.

```
bDef.angle = 50*Math.PI/180;
```

Otherwise you would probably be better off with a kinematic body.

Additionally you can set an angle through the setAsBox method.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried doing that, but it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Is passing the angle to setAsBox an option?

Comment: Ok, there is another method where I have to define center and angle, so it worked. But I am not sure if I should accept your anwser, since the solution is in your comment, not anwser.

Comment: I don't know. I am kind of new to participating in stackoverflow. ;-) I have edited my answer and included the solution from my comment though. So the solution is now part of the answer as well.

Answer (score 3):

I want to recommend you read the documentation, or at least see some guides(e.g. [good youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/dermetfan)).

Static bodies are not supposed to change position or angle. Use kinematic body.